# "Reflect.getMetadata is not a function" When Running Jenkins Job

Tags: node.js, typescript, jenkins, gradle, jestjs

I have a Jenkins job that run tests and build an image. I'm having trouble with the unit tests in the job.

```
task runTests(type: NpmTask) {
    dependsOn(tasks['lintTS'])
    args = ['run', 'test']
}
```

When I run locally everything works but when I run the job I get the following error -

```
> scim-api@0.0.1 test /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/e-commits_feature_handle-commits

> jest

FAIL src/app.controller.spec.ts

  ● Test suite failed to run
    TypeError: Reflect.getMetadata is not a function
      at Optional (../node_modules/@nestjs/common/decorators/core/optional.decorator.js:21:34)
      at ../node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:100:41
      at Object.__decorate (../node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:95:99)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/@nestjs/common/services/logger.service.js:118:29)
      at Object.<anonymous> (../node_modules/@nestjs/common/utils/load-package.util.js:3:26)
```

I don't have the @Optional decorator anywhere in my tests.

Do you have an idea why this could happen?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced it when doing testing in my NestJs API and I solved it by adding

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
```

into the top of my Test Case file.
I hope that this can help you.